# How can I use both jest-dom matchers and enzyme matchers in the same repo?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library, jest-dom

We have been using Enzyme for a long time to test our react components but have started the migration to React Testing Library step by step.

When trying to use the `toHaveValue` matcher in a RTL test it failes since the enzyme matcher with the same name is called instead. Is there a way I can "tell" a specific test file to use the matchers from jest-dom instead?

I have added both the enzyme and jest-dom matchers to my repository according to the installation docs.

Answer (score 0):

The `toHaveValue()` assertion is provided by react-testing-library's `jest-dom` (https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavevalue).

You should be able to force the `jest-dom` matchers (assertions) "before" whichever ones you have loaded previously (enzyme's, for example) by putting

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

at the top of your test.

See also:
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/379 and
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6243

A similar issue:
https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/208